# Dropdown menu wont stay same size as button

Tags: html, css

I have this dropdown menu that is acting horribly, the dropdown list is always bigger than the button, I tried changing the widths for both to match, but when changing screen size it gets all wonky. It should be easier to line this up, What am I doing wrong here?

HTML:

```
    <td>
       <div class="dropdown pull-left">
          <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true"><?php echo $text_campaign_dropdown;?><span class="caret"></span></button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" >
             <li class="campaign-dropdown-list">  <a href="<?php echo $order['edit']; ?>" data-toggle="tooltip"  class="btn btn-primary" id="campaign-edit" ><?php echo $button_edit; ?></i></a></li>
             <li class="campaign-dropdown-list">
                <button type="submit" id="campaign-archive" name="archiveButton" value="<?php echo $order['campaign_id']; ?>" onclick="javascript:changeFormAction('<?php echo $archive; ?>');">
                <?php echo $button_archive; ?>
                </button>
             </li>
             <li class="campaign-dropdown-list">
                <button type="submit" id="campaign-del" name="deleteButton" value="<?php echo $order['campaign_id']; ?>" onclick="javascript:changeFormAction('<?php echo $delete; ?>');">
                <?php echo $button_delete; ?>
                </button>
             </li>
          </ul>
       </div>
     </td>
```

CSS:

```
button.dropdown-toggle{
 margin-top: 0;
 border-top: 0;

}
ul.dropdown-menu{
  margin-top: -1px;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
    background: transparent;
}
li.campaign-dropdown-list{

    box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
    padding: 3px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgb(31,123,144) 0.2%,rgb(41,163,194) 100%);
    background-blend-mode: color-dodge;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;

}


li.campaign-dropdown-list a{
    color: white;
    background: transparent;
}

li.campaign-dropdown-list a:hover{
    color: yellow;
    background: transparent; !important
}


li.campaign-dropdown-list:hover{

        /* background: #333322 */
         background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgb(31,123,144) 0.2%,lightblue 100%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When working with CSS and HTML you have to keep in mind any declarations of size for a window are relative to the set screen resolution or size of the window being displayed (only applies if window is not in the maximized status). A way to avoid this is to DIRECTLY set the desired size in pixels rather than a ratio or percentage. Also remember that padding, margins, and borders will increase the size of any object you are declaring.